# Does the VirtualBox installer shutdown your Wi-Fi for everyone temporarily?

Tags: virtualbox

Whenever you download VirtualBox and it pops up the Wi-Fi warning and it says that it will shut down the Wi-Fi temporarily.

But I'm wondering if it shuts it down for only you or for everyone using it because I share Wi-Fi with other people connected to my home router.

Comment: "I share wifi with other people" – Do you mean other users on the same machine? Or users connected to the same wifi access point (e.g home router) but using different computers, smartphones, whatever?

Comment: It is only shutting it down on the machine you ate installing VirtualBox on. Not your overall Wi-Fi from the router. Only the PC you install VirtualBox on would have issues. But only temporary issues at most.

Comment: Only the PC you install VirtualBox on would have issues. But only temporary issues at most... That is what I posted.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and integrate your reply with it. All relevant information should be in the question, not in comments. Our short [tour] explains how the site is designed to work.

Comment: @KeeT In this case, my comment stands: You will only impact the Wi-Fi on your PC and not the Wi-Fi provided by the router you are connected to. It would honestly be shocking for any software to affect a router like that. It will only be your PC that is affected by the VirtualBox install.